# MYSQL query, multiple tables with average

Tags: mysql

Need help to put together a MYSQL query that returns the following (if it is possible). At the moment I extract the data I need with two queries but would be pleased if it was possible to accomplish with just one.

I have two tables. One document table that lists all available documents. I also have a table with ratings for the different documents. There can be multiple ratings for every document and I am interested in the average rating for a document.

Table document

```
+-------+------------+
| docId | docTitle   |
+----+---------------+
|  1    | Doc1 title |
|  2    | Doc2 title |
+-------+------------+
```

Table comments

```
+------------+---------------+
| docId      | commentRating |
+------------+---------------+
| 1          |    5          |
| 1          |    3          |
| 2          |    1          |
| 2          |    4          |
+------------+---------------+
```

Returned result from query

```
+----+------------+-----------+
| id | title      | avgRating |
+----+------------+-----------+
|  1 | Doc1 title |    4      |
|  2 | Doc2 title |    2,5    |
+----+------------+-----------+
```

Solved!
I used this query to get the result that I wanted:

```
SELECT doc.docId, doc.docTitle, doc.docThumbnail, averageRating
    from `document` as doc 
    Left join (
        select * , avg(commentRating) 
        as averageRating from comments 
        group by comments.docId
    )
    as rat On commentRating = doc.docid
```

Comment: We changed at the same time, but I was so slow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only needs average values, select it by aggregation function AVG() in grouped query:

```
 Select doc.docid as id , doc.docTitle , rat.average
 from document as doc
 Left join (
    select * , avg( commentRating ) as average
       -- , group_concat(rating) as allratings
    from comments
    group by commentDocId
    ) as rat
 On rat.commentDocId = doc.docid
```

Note: allratings returns all ratings for selected docId. If it's not useful, remove it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I though I would be able to "translate" my example to fit the actual names of my tables but I just can to it. I have updated my question so that it contains the real names of the tables and columns I use. Do you mind updating your answer to use those names aswell?

Comment: Finally manage to put the pieces together to get a query that was accepted and returned what I wanted. Thank you for your help!

Will update the question with the query i ran.